# jQuery - auto add toggle on element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have this code. Its for every single element. Is there a way to automate it? Because if I want to add element (job4 for example) I also need to add jQuery code.

```
$("#jobi1").click(function() {
    $("#job1").fadeIn(300);
});
$("#jobi2").click(function() {
    $("#job2").fadeIn(300);
});
$("#jobi3").click(function() {
    $("#job3").fadeIn(300);
});
```

Comment: add a common class to those elements and bind the same event for that class a single time. That will do the job.

Comment: Use classes, and DOM traversal, and show us what the HTML looks like, and how the elements are placed etc.

Comment: If it's for "every single element", you could do `$("*")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your job elements the same class and put the job identifier in a data-attribute, like this:

```
<button class="job" data-id="job1">job1<button>
<button class="job" data-id="job2">job2<button>
<button class="job" data-id="job3">job3<button>
```

And the javascript:

```
$('.job').on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#'+id).fadeIn(300);
});
```

Comment: I was actually 10 seconds faster, but it is ok. You need the rep more than I ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use a class and grab the ID from a data attribute

```
$(".job").on("click",function() {
  $(this).data("target").fadeIn(300);
});
```

using

```
<div class="job" data-target="job1">...</div>
```